# What is the default format for the Access token issued by Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, jwt, access-token

What is the default format for the Access token issued by Web API ?
I am working on the standard template for ASP.NET Web API with Individual User Accounts (for authentication).
As per my understanding the format is not JWT token format; but then what is the format of the token ? I tried to Base64 decode, but didn't work.
Also, as per my understanding the token contains information related to claims, please correct me if I am wrong.
Though I have been working with Web API for a while, I am asking this out of curiosity.

Any guidance in the right direction would be helpful. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

from the [oAuth 2.0 specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.4) (1.4, Access Token):

> Access tokens are credentials used to access protected resources.
> An access token is a string representing an authorization issued to
> the client.  The string is usually opaque to the client.  Tokens
> represent specific scopes and durations of access, granted by the
> resource owner, and enforced by the resource server and authorization
> server.
>
> ....
>
> The access token provides an abstraction layer, replacing different
> authorization constructs (e.g., username and password) with a single
> token understood by the resource server.  ....
>
> Access tokens can have different formats, structures, ... based on the
> resource    server security requirements.  Access token attributes and
> the    methods used to access protected resources ... are defined by companion specifications
> such    as [[RFC6750]](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750).

Bottom line: there is no "default format for Access token". It is something that the Authentication Server and Resource Server should agree on (AKA design by contract)